# Controller from package not found

Tags: laravel, controller, package

I am trying to make a package and I am new for it, everything is going fine, but when I tried to use controller from package like[image: folder structure and files]

but I get [image: error]
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Because your admincontroller extends controller and you used RoshanDev\MiePackage\Controller that same as the class name your admincontroller exetends.
Solution is change it with as:

```
use RoshanDev\MiePackage\Controller as ctr;
```

Comment: not helped, that the same controller I want to extend